# Convert a list of 1x1 dimensional arrays to list of floats in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, pandas

I have a list of the form:

```
[array([ 3755.16235032]),
 array([ 3755.16235032]),
 array([ 3755.16235032]),
 array([ 3755.16235032])]
```

I'd like to have a list of the form:

```
[3755.16235032,
 3755.16235032,
 3755.16235032,
 3755.16235032]
```

Each element of the first list was the result of a sci kit learn regressor. I want it in the second format so I can plot the classifier's predictions.

Comment: `[x[0] for x in array]`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want it as a 1D array of floats instead of a list of floats? You could just do, e.g., `np.array(lst).flatten()` or `np.concatenate(lst)` to get a flat array.

Comment: (If you really want a list, you could also do `list(np.array(lst).flatten())`, and it might be slightly faster than the listcomp… but for N=4, who cares?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alternate solution: Given `x` is your input `list`, either you can use `ravel()` from NumPy as

```
xlst = list(np.array(x).ravel())
print (xlst)
```

or you can use `flatten()` as

```
xlst = list(np.array(x).flatten())
print (xlst)
```

In case you just want the final answer as an array, you don't need to put `list` after `=`. And, in case your input `x` is already of type numpy array, replace `np.array(x).ravel()` by `x.ravel()`.

Alternately, as already mentioned in above answer, instead of using `list()` to convert to a list, you can also use `np.array(x).flatten().tolist()` and `np.array(x).ravel().tolist()`

Some time analysis for all the possible answers listed on this page inspired by the comments (thanks to the commentators) in one of the answers below (It's easy to put this here rather than in the comments due to formatting issues):

```
x = np.array([np.array([i]) for i in range(100000)])
%timeit np.concatenate(x).tolist()
%timeit np.hstack(x).tolist()
%timeit x.flatten().tolist()
%timeit x.ravel().tolist()
```

**Output**

```
10 loops, best of 3: 55.2 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 155 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.45 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.29 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think the differences in our timings have to do with the fact that your list `x` is an `np.array` of `np.array`s to start with, whereas I'm using a list of `np.array`s. I'll add my benchmarks to my answer too. It's interesting though, it seems that the majority of the time is spent on turning the list to an array (`np.array(my_list)` is what really adds to the times for `flatten` and `ravel`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.concatenate` to avoid manually iterating:

```
my_list = [np.array([ 3755.16235032]),
 np.array([ 3755.16235032]),
 np.array([ 3755.16235032]),
 np.array([ 3755.16235032])]

new_list = np.concatenate(my_list).tolist()

>>> new_list
[3755.16235032, 3755.16235032, 3755.16235032, 3755.16235032]
```

## Benchmarks:

Based on the extensive discussion in the comments, here is my benchmarking:

```
my_list = [np.random.randn(1) for _ in range(100000)]

def concat_method(my_list=my_list):
    return np.concatenate(my_list).tolist()

def hstack_method(my_list=my_list):
    return np.hstack(my_list).tolist()

def flatten_method(my_list=my_list):
    return np.array(my_list).flatten().tolist()

def ravel_method(my_list=my_list):
    return np.array(my_list).ravel().tolist()

import timeit

>>> timeit.timeit(concat_method, number=100) / 100
0.025655772869977226
>>> timeit.timeit(hstack_method, number=100) / 100
0.1172302443100125
>>> timeit.timeit(ravel_method, number=100) / 100
0.041237239889997
>>> timeit.timeit(flatten_method, number=100) / 100
0.0412076849100049
```

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for a list fo floats, not an array of floats. I have no idea _why_ that's what he wants, but…

Comment: Not sure it's any better than a listcomp for N=4, but still, at the very least it's worth it for the OP to learn how to do this if he's going to be using numpy.

Comment: I actually have no idea. If it mattered, I'd `%timeit`. But if it doesn't matter, and it probably doesn't, `concatenate` is probably simpler to understand. (The only reason I put `flatten` before `concatenate` in my comment on the question is that it's what I happened to think of first, not that I thought it would be better…)

Comment: You're right that it probably doesn't matter... but my curiosity got the better of me (I know deep down inside you were itching to know, too...). On a list of 100000 arrays, `flatten` takes ~0.041 seconds,  and concat takes ~0.026. This includes transforming to a list using `tolist()` in both cases.

Comment: OK, now that you started that, you have to compare them both to `ravel` from Bazingaa's answer (didn't think of that one…), and maybe compare `a.tolist()` to `list(a)` separately. Oh, and how fast is using the obvious listcomp by comparison? :)

Comment: `ravel` makes it in ~0.041 seconds (same as `flatten`). using `list(a)` instead of `a.tolist()` seems to consistently add about 0.002 seconds to each method, interestingly (but that's negligible, really)

Comment: Now you've got to try `hstack` from Wen's answer… and someone's going to come along and suggest plain old `stack`, and `reshape`. Look what you got yourself into.

Comment: `hstack`: 0.11 secs, `stack`+`reshape`:0.13 secs. I think I've given my computer a nice little workout! At least OP should be happy that there seem to be *a lot* of options!

Comment: Motivated by your comments, I updated my answer with some time analysis.  You may have a look above. Thank you @sacul and abarnert

Answer (score 1):

By using `hstack`

```
np.hstack(my_list).tolist()
Out[180]: [3755.16235032, 3755.16235032, 3755.16235032, 3755.16235032]
```